Appium UI Test Delays in the Maui Bottom Sheet on Android
I'm experiencing significant performance issues with Appium UI tests when interacting with elements inside the the49 Maui bottom sheet on Android. Normally, finding an element by Id takes less than a second, but when the element is within the bottom sheet, it takes around 25 seconds.What should I do for finding elements faster?
